# New HBase installation very slow

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

I've just installed HBase 0.94.2 on my iMac, running Sun Java 7 and Mac OS 10.8.2.

I do have a development Hadoop instance, however for now am running HBase in standalone mode.

Unfortunately, many basic operations are taking over 30 seconds to execute:

```
magoo:bin mattpainter$ ./hbase shell
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 0.94.2, r1395367, Sun Oct  7 19:11:01 UTC 2012

hbase(main):002:0> list 'table'
TABLE                                                                                                                                                                       
2012-10-20 08:26:38.903 java[41217:1703] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
0 row(s) in 33.6460 seconds

hbase(main):003:0>
```

Looking in the logs, we see this:

```
12/10/20 08:24:58 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 26667ms for sessionid 0x13a7a7744270005, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
12/10/20 08:24:58 WARN zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient ZooKeeper exception: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/master
12/10/20 08:24:58 INFO util.RetryCounter: Sleeping 2000ms before retry #1...
12/10/20 08:24:59 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server /fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1:2181
12/10/20 08:25:04 INFO client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Client will not SASL-authenticate because the default JAAS configuration section 'Client' could not be found. If you are not using SASL, you may ignore this. On the other hand, if you expected SASL to work, please fix your JAAS configuration.
12/10/20 08:25:04 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1/fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1:2181, initiating session
12/10/20 08:25:04 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1/fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1:2181, sessionid = 0x13a7a7744270005, negotiated timeout = 40000
```

What could be so wrong that an out-of-the-box install with zero configuration (apart from setting `JAVA_HOME` in `hbase-env.sh`) would exhibit this behaviour?

Many thanks,
Matt

Comment: Hrm. A [Mac Java 7 related issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-1477)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [ZOOKEEPER-1477](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-1477) was indeed the culprit.

I upgraded from JDK1.7.0_04 to JDK1.7.0_09, modified my `base-env.sh` accordingly and all now works zippily.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your JVM is defaulting to IPv6 traffic.  Try adding -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true to your HBASE_OPTS envvar (just a few lines below JAVA_HOME in hbase-env.sh), and restarting HBase.

There are other ways of forcing IPv4 (editing sysctl.conf)

Comment: Thanks for this - this doesn't seem to have fixed the issue, but upgrading my JDK a few notches did. Curious.